# PHP - Notice: Undefined variable: _REQUESTS

Tags: php

Hi i'm creating a site with a  search box this is already done in asp and im redoing it in php (which I am new too) and it will take you to another page where it searches the db using sql.
The search-process.php file is below

```
<?php
$db = realpath("db\unibookv2.mdb");
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or exit('Cannot start ADO.');
$connStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
Data Source=$db";
$conn->Open($connStr);



$sql = "SELECT * FROM ubuser WHERE usr_firstname LIKE '%" . $_REQUESTS['searchinput'] .  "%' OR usr_lastname LIKE '%" . $_REQUESTS['searchinput'] . "%' ORDER BY '%" . $_REQUESTS['orderlist'] . "%' ";

$userRs = $conn->Execute($sql);
if (!$userRs)
    {exit("DBMS Error..!");}
?>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>PHP Search Results - ADO-COM connection!</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/unibookStyle.css" />
</head>
<!-- #include FILE="include/header.asp") -->


<body>
<div id="container"><!-- start container -->

<h2>USER DATABASE</h2>

<!-- start of dynamic html page -->
<h2>PHP/ADO-COM (MS Access) basic parameterised example</h2>
<h3>You searched for : '<?php echo $_REQUEST['searchinput']; ?>' - 

<hr align="left" width="658" />

<?php
// example of testing for EOF in resultset  
if (!$userRs->EOF)
{
echo "one or more records found<br />";
}
else
{
echo "sorry, no records found<br />";
}
?>

<!-- start of html table -->
    <table border="0" width="758" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

    <!-- create the first (heading) row in standard HTML -->
    <tr class="tableheading">
        <td><b>Usr_id</b></td><td><b>firstname</b></td><td>&nbsp;<b>lastname</b></td><td>&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
<!-- loop in PHP to retrieve all records -->
<?php
    $nrecs=0;
    while (!$userRs->EOF) { 
    $nrecs++;   
    ?>
    <tr>
    <!-- use in-line PHP to display the data -->
        <td><?php echo $userRs->Fields['usr_id']->Value ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $userRs->Fields['usr_firstname']->Value ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $userRs->Fields['usr_lastname']->Value ?></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- important line as it moves the resultset 'cursor' -->
    <?php $userRs->MoveNext() ?>
<?php } ?>
</table>


<?php
// close and destroy object instances
$userRs->Close();
$conn->Close();

$userRs = null;
$conn = null;

// display records found to page
echo "<br />Number of records found: " . $nrecs;
?>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr align="left" width="658">

<input type="button" value="< Back to Search Page" OnClick="top.location='default.asp'">

<!-- #include FILE="include/sidebar.asp") -->

<!-- #include FILE="include/footer.asp") -->
</div>
<!-- end main page content -->

</body>
</html>
```

This is the error I am getting about the variables being undefined, im assuming this is the "[searchinput]" twice and once for the "[orderlist]"

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _REQUESTS in H:\STUDENT\S0190204\part1\search-process.php on line 10 Notice: Undefined variable: _REQUESTS in H:\STUDENT\S0190204\part1\search-process.php on line 10 Notice: Undefined variable: _REQUESTS in H:\STUDENT\S0190204\part1\search-process.php on line 10
```

Other problems are the search term used does not work and the order by also, but i have a feeling these problems are going to be solved by the same thing

Comment: I think it should be $_REQUEST.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo by OP.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Scripting_Flaw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be `$_REQUEST` and not `$_REQUESTS`.Also beware of [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) since you are directly using the values.Use prepare statemnts to prevent sql injnection.

From the documentation

> $_REQUEST is an associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET,
>
> $_POST and $_COOKIE.
> The variables in $_REQUEST are provided to the script via the GET,
> POST, and COOKIE input mechanisms and therefore could be modified by
> the remote user and cannot be trusted. The presence and order of
> variables listed in this array is defined according to the PHP
> variables_order configuration directive

You can look into the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)  for more

Comment: It makes sense since you're serving the response to `an HTTP request`, you can't respond to multiple `HTTP requests`.

Comment: That solved it I can now search by terms also, ther only issue is the order by is not working still. Any idea why? either way thanks for your answer